# mysqli query result is displayed as"Array" in php. How to retrieve the individual values from it?

Tags: php, arrays, mysqli

Below is my code to retrieve the column names from the table "COLUMNS" of database "INFORMATION_SCHEMA".

```
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT COLUMN_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'CustomersTable'") or die(mysqli_error($con));

$columns = $result;
foreach ($columns as $column){
  echo $column;
}
```

what I get echoed is `ArrayArrayArrayArrayArrayArrayArrayArray`. However, if I write

```
mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
```

instead of

```
$columns = $result;
```

then I get only the first value of the array echoed.

How do I get all the values echoed as I expect it to be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `while()` loop along with [mysqli_fetch_assoc](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php):-

```
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT COLUMN_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'CustomersTable'") or die(mysqli_error($con));

while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
  print_r($row);//array contains `COLUMN_NAME`.
  //based on printed value you can get how to do echo easily
}
```

Comment: Upvoted all answers, but accepting this one as it caught me first and explained sufficient for me. Thanks @Alive to Die.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `mysqli_fetch_assoc` inside of a `while()` loop:

```
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT COLUMN_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'CustomersTable'") or die(mysqli_error($con));

while( $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
{
    // $row now contains an array with the `COLUMN_NAME` inside.
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To get all the values `echo`'ed, you need to use `while()` loop with `mysqli_fetch_assoc()`

```
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT COLUMN_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'CustomersTable'") or die(mysqli_error($con));
while($rows = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    print_r($rows); // this contains all the necessary data that you are looking for...
}
```

Here is reference to [mysqli_fetch_assoc()](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php)

Answer (score 1):

using loop you can access all values

```
 $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT COLUMN_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'CustomersTable'") or die(mysqli_error($con));

 while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result){
        print_r($row);
 }
```